# Необходимые компоненты Visual Studio 2010 для x64

Tags: ide, visual-studio

Здравствуйте!

Устанавливаю майкрософт студио ультимайт 2010, выдаёт:

> `Необходимые компоненты Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 для 64-разрядных компьютеров (x64): [2] Error: Installation failed for component Необходимые компоненты Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 для 64-разрядных компьютеров (x64). MSI returned error code 1603`

Помогите, пожалуйста, а то мне надо домашку по СИ на курсах сделать!

Благодарю.

PS Скачал все с официального сайта.

Comment: А вы случайно не x86 версию скачали и ставите на Windows x64 ?

Comment: Я когда с официального сайта майкрософт какчал, там не было отдельно для 64. Может вы поделитесь ссылкой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотреть [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee225240.aspx)

Установить отдельный компонент: "Необходимые компоненты 64-разрядной версии Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (x64)"